# В чем причина ошибки вызова sysinfo?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Добавление такого кода

```
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

struct sysinfo si = { 0 };

sysinfo(&si);
```

вызывает ошибки на этапе компиляции:

> `error: conflicting declaration 'sysinfo& si'`
> `error: 'si' has a previous declaration as 'sysinfo si'`
> `warning: unused variable 'si'`

В то время, как то же самое на Ubuntu отлично собирается и выполняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как оказалось, в NDK не поддерживается этот системый вызов. В `./android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/sysinfo.h`

```
#if 0 /* MISSING FROM BIONIC */
extern int sysinfo (struct sysinfo *info);
#endif /* MISSING */
```

Поскольку мне все-таки sysinfo нужен, я добавил тело функции как ассемблерный исходник. Объявление:

```
extern int sysinfo (struct sysinfo *info);
```

и сама функция:

```
#define __NR_sysinfo 116
#include <sys/linux-syscalls.h>

    .text 
    .type sysinfo, #function 
    .globl sysinfo 
    .align 4 
    .fnstart 
sysinfo: 
    .save   {r4, r7} 
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, r7} 
    ldr     r7, =__NR_sysinfo 
    swi     #0 
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, r7} 
    movs    r0, r0 
    bxpl    lr 
    b       __set_syscall_errno 
    .fnend
```

[Using sysinfo in Android NDK](http://bertleung.wordpress.com/2011/02/28/using-sysinfo-in-android-ndk/).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переименовать si во что-нибудь другое...